# Change position of commands

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why my element first show and after that he is visible he is doing animation? :/ does exist any possibility to change order?

```
function open(element){
  $(element).animate({margin: "25px 0px 0px 0px"});
  $(element).find(".describe").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`.animate()` is asynchronous, `.show()` occurs immediately.

You can use the callback of `.animate()` to delay until it finishes.

```
function open(element) {
    $(element).animate({margin: "25px 0px 0px 0px"}, function()
        $(element).find(".describe").show();
    });
}
```

Comment: Is here any way how I can animate method show()? Becuase right now it just come out of nowhere..

Comment: Use `.fadeIn()` to make it fade in slowly.

Comment: Ty so much dude :)